# Haskell: Is there a left-side identity for the infix (`:`) operator?

Tags: list, haskell

In other words, what syntax (if any) could I use in place of `XXX` in the following implementation of filter:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ []     = []
filter' f (x:xs) =
  let n = if f x then x else XXX
  in  n:(filter' f xs)
```

I'm aware of the following alternative implementation (which is recursive and only prepends) but would still be curious if the infix operator has a LHS identity.

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ []     = []
filter' f (x:xs)
  | f x = x:(filter' f xs)
  | otherwise = filter' f xs
```

Comment: `:` is a constructor. Constructors cannot have identities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is none.  This can be seen because

```
ghci> length (undefined : [])
1
```

so no matter what element you put there, you will always get a length of 1.

How about this phrasing:

```
filter' f (x:xs) =
    let n = if f x then (x:) else id
    in  n (filter' f xs)
```

Comment: Or even shorter, `(if f x then (x:) else id) (filter' f xs)`

Answer (score 2):

Handwave alert: the following is strictly speaking a lie (because of `undefined` and such), but it's still a useful idea.

One key property of types defined with Haskell `data` declarations is that they are **free**: the set of values for a `data` type is isomorphic to the set of **normal-form terms** (fully evaluated expressions) of that type.  If two terms of the type are different, then they have different values.

From this it follows that `x : xs` and `xs` (in the same scope) must be different lists, simply because they are different terms.

Put a bit differently, the semantics of `data` types is that if you pattern match on a constructor application you always get back the same constructor and its arguments.  For example, these two expressions are guaranteed to be `True`, no matter what `x` and `xs` may be:

```
case [] of
    []   -> True
    x:xs -> False

case (x:xs) of
    []     -> False
    x':xs' -> x == x' && xs == xs'
```

The left identity value you're looking for would be a counterexample to the second expression here.  Ergo, no such value exists.

Answer (score 2):

There is none, but `++` *does* have an identity, namely `[]`. So this would work as well:

```
filter' _ [] = []
filter' f (x:xs) =
     let n = if f x then [x] else [] 
     in n ++ (filter' f xs)
```

This is the same as @luqui's answer (as you could prove) only less efficient
, but it keeps things a bit lower-order.

Comment: Honestly I doubt it's any less efficient. It'd be fun to find out

Comment: Even nicer: `filter' f (x:xs) = [x | f x] ++ filter' f xs`

Comment: @luqui: Your solution reduces to `if f x then x : filter' f xs else filter' f xs` slightly more quickly than mine (no need to inline the definition of `++`) - but, yeah, my guess about efficiency assumes an extremely naive execution model and I suppose GHC with any optimization level would emit the same code for both :-)